# Respond to ping from different interface than inbound interface in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ping, network-interface

I'm trying to figure out if I need further configuration to allow outbound traffic to work on a different interface than inbound traffic.

My setup is two servers.

Server1 has `eth1` on VLAN100 and `eth2` on VLAN200.

Server2 has `eth1` on VLAN100 and no interface on VLAN200.

Server1 `eth1`'s IP is 10.1.0.2 in the 10.1.0.0/24 subnet with gateway1 10.1.0.1.

Server1 `eth2`'s IP is 10.2.0.2 in the 10.2.0.0/24 subnet with gateway2 10.2.0.1.

Server2 `eth1`'s IP is 10.1.0.3 in the 10.1.0.0/24 subnet with gateway1 10.1.0.1.

Gateway1 (10.1.0.1) will route 10.2.0.0/24 traffic through gateway2 (10.2.0.1) and vice versa.

Server1 can ping Server2's `eth1` interface (10.1.0.2 -> 10.1.0.3).
Server2 can ping Server1's `eth1` interface (10.1.0.3 -> 10.1.0.2).

When Server2 pings Server1's `eth2` IP (10.2.0.2), the Echo request is received on Server1, but Server1 does not respond.
The source of the ping is 10.1.0.3, so Server1 should route the return traffic through its eth1 interface (10.1.0.2).  So I think the round trip for this ping should be:

**Flow of Inbound ICMP Echo Request**

```
Server2 eth1 (10.1.0.3 - VLAN100)
Gateway1     (10.1.0.1 - VLAN100)
Gateway2     (10.2.0.1 - VLAN200)
Server1 eth2 (10.2.0.2 - VLAN200)
```

**Expected Flow of Outbound ICMP Echo Reply**

```
Server1 eth1 (10.1.0.2 - VLAN100)
Gateway1     (10.1.0.1 - VLAN100)
Server2 eth2 (10.1.0.3 - VLAN100)
```

Via `tcpdump` on Server1, I can see that the ICMP packets from Server2 are reaching Server1's `eth2` interface, but the ICMP response is not leaving Server1 on any interface.  I can't figure out why they are being dropped in Server1.

**EDIT: Further information**

Both subnets have netmask 255.255.255.0 and the interfaces have been confirmed to also have netmask 255.255.255.0.

Server1 has default gateway through 10.1.0.1

Server2 has default gateway through 10.1.0.1

```
Server1:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.2.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

Server2:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: Your description is unclear to me. Can you provide the route tables and netmasks for each system please. It sounds like server2 does not have a default gateway or route for 10.1 via gateway or there is a netmask issue.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Server 1 sees a packet arriving from 10.1.0.0/24 on `eth2` with subnet  10.2.0.0/24, while at the same time there exists another interface `eth1` with subnet 10.1.0.0/24.

The default configuration of the Linux kernel is to interpret this as a routing mistake (a packet from 10.1.0.*/24 should arrive on `eth1`, not on `eth2`) and therefore it decides to drop the packet, in order to not flood the network with packets in response to the stuff the "misconfigured" router(s) do. Which is the reason you don't see an ICMP echo reply.

There are ways to configure this behavior via `/proc` or `/sys`, but I'd have to lookup the details. In any case, it may require some fiddling to get this intended behavior (and you'll have to be careful not to break other things while doing that).

So the *easy* way is to fix your network topology and subnetting ranges, and set up something more standard. You didn't explain *why* you think you need this particular setup; there may be a way to achieve what you want while still adhering to networking best practices. So your question may be an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Therefore, please edit the question and explain your main goal.